# What is the difference between Task.Run() and await Task.Run()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Following program is designed using general Task.Run() and using async and await (asynchronous). In both cases a different Thread is taken from Thread pool for new task. So, what is the difference? Asynchronous means it should use the main thread and free it until task completed. But it is also using another thread rather than using main thread.

```
public class Worker2
{
    public bool IsComplete { get; private set; }
    internal void DoWork()
    {
        this.IsComplete = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Work.");
        Task.Run(new Action(LongOperation));
        Console.WriteLine("Work Completed");
        IsComplete = true;
    }

    private void LongOperation()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("long operation thread thread :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);//Thread Id = 7. it is different from main thread id.
            Console.WriteLine("Working!");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

//And asynchronous

```
public class Worker2
{
    public bool IsComplete { get; private set; }
    internal async void DoWork()
    {
        this.IsComplete = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Work.");       
        await LongOperation();
        Console.WriteLine("Work Completed");
        IsComplete = true;
    }

    private Task LongOperation()
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("long operation thread thread :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("Working!");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to format your code - indent everything appropriately, block quote it by 4 characters so it *all* appears as code, and remove the blank line between each useful line.

Comment: Please note that in the first example, you get "Work Complete" printed before it actually completes.

Comment: I am asking about how threads are used from thread pool in both cases.

Comment: @user3783446 the same, as you're effectively using the same code in both cases.  The only difference is in one of them you're not awaiting the result.

Comment: Yes, I am using same code in both cases except the later one is asynchronous.

Comment: In first case, the used thread for new task will not be release until task completed. and in later case the used thread for new task will be released to thread pool and will not be blocked until task completed. After task completed a new thread will be assigned. Am I right?

Comment: It's the same in both cases, the only difference is whether you're awaiting the result or fire-and-forget.  They're both asynchronous, they both run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your response. So, in both cases new thread is used from thread pool (other than main thread)?

Comment: I read a post on link http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html. Here it is suggested that we should use await Task.Run(() => LongOperation()); instead of await LongOperation(); So, is there any difference between two?

Comment: The first snippet just tells lies, it says "Work Completed" when it is not and sets IsCompleted to *true* when the worker thread is still running.  The second snippet does not lie.  The difference is most obvious when you put a Console.WriteLine() call after the Sleep().

Comment: Hans and Yacoub are absolutely right; the difference between these code samples is that one is lying to the user and the other is correct! Just saying that the work is completed does not make it so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between Task.Run() and await Task.Run()?

The first starts a task and then does the work immediately after that task, *before the task completes*.

The second starts a task and then does **different** work until the task is completed, at which point it does the work after the task.

Let's make an analogy. Your first program is like doing this:

- Hire someone to mow the lawn.
- Tell your spouse the lawn is mowed.
- Go watch Netflix.

Your second program is:

- Hire someone to mow the lawn.
- Watch Netflix while the lawn is being mowed.
- When the lawn is done being mowed and the movie is over, tell spouse the lawn is mowed.

Clearly those are very different workflows. Both are asynchronous, but only the latter has an *asynchronous wait* in it. We *asynchronously wait* to tell the spouse that the lawn is mowed *until it actually is mowed*.

Comment: The 2nd program more fits your first analogy. THe first program is more like hire someone to mow the lawn and watch netflix, but you tell your spouse it's being done even though the guy is still bussy.

Comment: @Batavia: That's what I said.

Comment: hmm, could have sworn you had them reversed. my bad

Comment: This is the best analogy on `async` and `Task` i have seen in a while !

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstood what asynchronous code means. Whenever you call *any* function which passes(*delegates*) the actual code execution to some other entity(other dedicated thread, thread pool, etc.) and the function immediately returns you have an asynchronous call. An asynchronous call is the antipode to a blocking call.

In C# there are a few method to write an asynchronous code and `await`/`async` just make writing simpler. It adds nothing in terms of functional to the language. It is just syntactic sugar to make programs easier to write by providing a way to write asynchronous code in the same style we write blocking code.

That being said, `Task.Run(new Action(LongOperation));` is an asynchronous call as well as `LongOperation()` from your second snippet. The difference between them, is that in the first example, when `Task.Run` returns the code which immediately follows that line gets executed immediately(provided no thread switch happened). And in the second example the lines which follow `await` get executed only when `LongOperation` completed on some thread provided by the thread pool(`DoWork` immediately returns when it encounters `await`).

I recommend you to read more about `TPL` and `async`/`await`. There are plenty blog posts out there about both, not to mention great books covering all these features in details.